# Realization of 2D/3D datasets outside ptd folder in petrel-plugin required

Tags: plugins, petrel

I had designed a plug in  ocean for Petrel 2012.2 which used to bring out all the 2D realized files outside ptd folder but now I am facing two issues in it :1) i want to upgraded it to 2014 petrel version which we are using now and secondly I want the 3D files also to be pulled out from the same plug in. Please help if anyone can.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: HI Giel i am working in an oil and gas company who need sto make some plugins for a software known as petrel which is used for geophysical and geological interpretation.I need to design a plug in for petrel software in Ocean such that it gets embeded inot the software since petrel understands ocean only.

Comment: In regard to the previous comment I already had a plug in which was able to reduce the project size by taking out the internally realized files out side the ptd folder which was compatible with 2012.2 and now we are using 2014 and higher.whenever we load some 2d seismic or 3d seismic data sets in petrel .the software always creates an internal format file within its ptd folder.Now if keep retaining the seismic data sets within the project the size of the project becomes bulky and at times may get corrupted as well.

Comment: so the solution to it is designing a plug in to take the realized 2d/3d data sets outside the ptd folder